# Assigning Edge Loops and Merging Uneven Loops

Tags: modeling

[image: My Example]Is any set of edges that form a ring continuously considered an edge loop? I'm asking because I have a ring of edges that connect end to end to form a loop. However, I'm unable to select this edge loop in any method. Now I'm not sure how the ring of edges was originally created (maybe it wasn't Extruded classically, maybe it was assembled by connecting the edges in some manner, etc) but it surely is a continuous loop of edges. It seems Blender is not recognizing my edge loop as an edge loop. Is there some way to designate my edge loop so that Blender can recognize it as an edge loop?

My goal is to "dissolve" extraneous edge loops, (as an example, in my picture, dissolving/deleting/merging/etc so that the result is as if you were to merge the highlighted middle loop to the B loop). By the way, can this be done if the loops are not uniform in shape/size as in my pic? It should be noted that the vertices, however, are consistent of a loop in terms of number and how they connect they connect in relation to each other, only it just isn't even).

Thanks guys!

Comment: your mesh is triangulated. Look at the faces. They are all triangles (tris). This prevents you to select an edge loop. In *Edit* mode, select all verts (A) and use the viewport menu *Face > Tris to Quads* (Alt+J) to convert the mesh to quads. Then try again.

Comment: For Blender to recognize the features you want to preserve automatically and generally, it would have to come up with an **unambiguous** topological definition of a loop.. for any vertex, which exit  to choose. On an arbitrarily triangulated mesh, this is unlikely to find the path you want. On a ring of quads, it is much more likely.. the second exit every time finds the principal curvatures of a mesh that is well-formed for deformation or subdivision. You could do this by hand relatively quickly.. would that be acceptable?

Comment: Blunder thanks for the answer, and thanks Robin Betts for the explanation. I know Blender a little better now because of you guys!

Comment: Robin, do what by hand? I'm about to try what Blunder suggested, to convert the mesh to quads with the Tris to Quads option. Is that what you're talking about? But in general, by hand is ok for a few instances, but when things are numerous, it can get cumbersome. it's better for me if there is a non-tedious solution. Thanks again!